# GWT RequestBuilder problem

Tags: jsp, gwt, insert, request, response

I'm trying to instert an jsp in our gwt application. I'm using the request builder for that. Here my code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/my-spring-example/hello.htm";
RequestBuilder rb = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);
RequestCallback callback = new RequestCallback() {
 public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
  spring.setHTML("Die Daten konnten nicht geladen werden");
 }

 public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
  String responseAsText = response.getText();
  if (responseAsText.equals("") || responseAsText == null ){
   spring.setHTML("Der String ist leer");   
  } else {
   spring.setHTML(responseAsText);
  }
 }
};

try {
 rb.sendRequest(null, callback);
} catch (RequestException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If i call http://localhost:8080/my-spring-example/hello.htm, the response in firebug is:

```
<head><title>Hello :: Spring 3 Application</title></head>
<body>
 <h1>Hello World, Spring 3.0!</h1>
 <p>Es gibt 32 Einträge</p>
</body>
```

If i make the call over our gwt application, the response in firebug is empty string.

If i i call http://localhost:8080/my-spring-example/hello.htm, the response in wireshark is:

```
<head><title>Hello :: Spring 3 Application</title></head>\n
<body>\n
\t<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.0!</h1>\n
\t<p>Es gibt 32 Eintr\344ge</p>\n
</body>
```

If i make the call over our gwt application, the response in wireshark is the same:

```
<head><title>Hello :: Spring 3 Application</title></head>\n
<body>\n
\t<h1>Hello World, Spring 3.0!</h1>\n
\t<p>Es gibt 32 Eintr\344ge</p>\n
</body>
```

I can't understand, what is wrong....the call is made correctly, response comes, but something happens, so the gwt client shows only empty string as response. I'm pretty confused....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem...for the jsp call i'm using the localhost, but i'm calling the webapp via another host. I must follow "Same Origin Policy" for JavaScript and now ist everything working fine.

**edit:** the jsp can be insert only, if you use same host and protocol for the call. For example - i'm calling our application over `http://www.mycompany.com:8080/gwt-client/`. For the jsp was the call `http://localhost:8080/my-spring-example/hello.htm`. The jsp and webapplication are on different hosts. If i change the jsp call to `http://www.mycompany.com:8080/my-spring-example/hello.htm`, then works.